# "will es noch mal wissen"

Tags: meaning, translation

The literal meaning, "wants to know it again", does not fit the context.

What does the phrase mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Closest might be „meet a challenge once again“. If for example German chancellor Angela Merkel is applying for chancelorship again after 2 terms of office the papers might write „Sie will es noch einmal wissen“. It includes the question: Am I still good enough to make it? (That's what she wants to find out.) However it actually isn't used if you really doubt it.

Comment: I wound two other translations: *...wanted to give it a try once again* and *...still had something to proove*. They don't fit perfectly, but the right meaning lies somewhere between them.

Comment: „… wanted to give it a try once again“ sounds too vague and at the same time too complicated in my ears, while „…still had something to prove“ is closer but not quite it – sounds more like a youngster who has to impress the world rather than the veteran that wants to challenge their fate agein.

Comment: That's what I meant, they are not correct, but go in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

One way to say this is: *Merkel will go for it again.*

Comment: Better: *Merkel is going for it again*